# Salesforce Napili Community: forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface Override Not Working

Tags: community, lightning, napili

Trying to override the standard profile menu in a Napili community and following the documentataion.

I have the following code in a component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]" default="Option 1, Option 2"/>
<ui:menu >
    <ui:menuTriggerLink aura:id="trigger" label="Profile Menu"/>
    <ui:menuList class="actionMenu" aura:id="actionMenu">
        <ui:actionMenuItem label="Test1"/>
        <ui:actionMenuItem label="Test2"/>
        <ui:actionMenuItem label="Test3"/>
    </ui:menuList>
</ui:menu>
```

Copied straight from the documentation.

I also set the User Profile Component to my custom "CommunityProfileMenu" component:
[image]

However, I'm still seeing the standard profile menu in my page.

[image]

Is there an issue with overriding these in Sandbox currently?

Comment: Have you publish the changes? I have copied and pasted your code and it shows me a custom menu

Answer (score 1):

To view the custom profile menu go to the Community Builder and select Settings>Theme and click the Customise option next to the layout type you wish to add the new menu in.

Then the new profile component should show under the user profile component drop down list as below. If you select it then it should be displayed. If the custom component is not displayed then that would probably be due to an error in the component.

For it to be visible make the change on the Inner section of the Theme Layout

[image]